# Protractor: Firefox browser opens but URL is not launched

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, jasmine

I am trying to run TestCase in Firefox browser.

Result is :  Firefox browser opens, but URL is not loading.

> FIREFOX browser - 53
>
> Selenium- webdriver - 3.6.0
>
> NPM - 3.10.10
>
> Protractor - 5.2.2

**CONFIG_FILE:**

```
     var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;
     var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-
      reporter');
     var fs = require('fs');
     require('protractor/built/logger').Logger.logLevel = 1;
  exports.config = {

framework: 'jasmine2',
specs : './Spec/LIST/ListPage_EM_Acc_Spec.js',
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'firefox',
    'moz:firefoxOptions': {
        'args': ['--safe-mode']
    }
},
allScriptsTimeout: 500000,
ignoreUncaughtExceptions: true,
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    isVerbose: true,
    showColors: true,
    includeStackTrace: true,
    displaySpecDuration: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 360000,
    print: function () {
    }
},
onPrepare: function(){
    browser.manage().window().maximize();          // set browser size...
    rmDir('C:/Users/***/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/protractor/Workspace/Reports/Download');
    global.isAngularSite = function(flag){
        browser.driver.ignoreSynchronization = !flag;
    };
    // Remove files in Specified Directory

    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
        spec: {
            displayStacktrace: true,
            displayFailuresSummary: true
        }
    }));
    var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
        consolidateAll: true,
        savePath: './Reports/JunitXMLprotractor-result/',
        cleanDestination: true,
        filePrefix: 'xmloutput'
    }));
    //require('./Data/waitReady.js');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
        new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
            savePath: './Reports/Screenshots/',
            takeScreenshots: true,
            takeScreenshotsOnlyOnFailures: true,
            consolidateAll: true,
            showPassed: true,
            // filePrefix: sessionId + 'AutomationReport',
            filePrefix: 'AutomationReport',
            cleanDestination: true,
        })
    );
},

};
```

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce your problem but there's some information you still need to provide, such as: 1 - if you run Firefox on `directConnect` or using `selenium Server` 2 - what happens if you do not use the `moz:firefoxOptions` key 3 - the version of `geckodriver` used will help as well 4 - is it an Angular app, or not 5 - have you ever ran any tests using Protractor on Firefox?

Comment: Thanks for reply Raul.                       1.Tried Both. But will use Direct connect    2. Browser just open's and stays     3.geckodriver **0.10.0**       4.launching page is not angular ,after navigation to other page is angular.            5.With firefox trying for first. Have run with chrome. working like charm.

Comment: Would suggest to first clean up your config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keasav, I understood your problem after your reply, and what's causing that behavior is the (very) old version of the `geckodriver` that you are using and the `Firefox` version as well.

1 - So the latest `geckodriver` version is 0.19.1 (and yours is 0.10.0, but many changes have been included since that build was released), and the latest `Firefox` is now at 57 (but you're using 53).

2 - I just ran a few tests on the `Firefox v57 using geckodriver v0.19.1` and everything is fine using the `Selenium Server`, as well as using `directConnect: true`. The capabilities used are exactly the same as those you provided in your question.

3 - Consider updating your `Firefox and geckodriver`.

4 - Don't forget to update your `webdriver-manager`. The current version is 12.0.6. To find what version you're using, execute `webdriver-manager version`.

5 - As an advice, when facing a problem with different browsers, it's easy to find the solution if you're using a sandbox project, just to be sure that the browser binaries are the ones you want. For example, in the capabilities object, you can specify the `firefoxPath` value.

6 - Read the following details provided by the maintainers: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3823#issuecomment-273615047

Comment: Thanks Raul. After upgrading the geckodriver to latest version and ff latest. URL is loading.